# How do I make vcpkg install packages system wide

Tags: package-management, cmake

My system package manager `dnf` (Im using fedora Linux) doesn't have an `imgui` package or an `assimp` package so I decided to use `vcpkg` for installing `imgui` and `assimp`.

The problem I think is that `find_package` doesn't work for packages installed with `vcpkg` because the `vcpkg` directory is in my home directory and I guess `cmake` has no way of knowing that `imgui` was installed in my home directory.

This is the error I get when trying to build with cmake:

```shellsession
$ cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -S .. -B .
-- Submodule update CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:40 (find_package): Could not find a package configuration file provided by "imgui" with
any of the following names: imguiConfig.cmake imgui-config.cmake Add
the installation prefix of "imgui" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
"imgui_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files. If
"imgui" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
been installed.
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

So how do I make `vcpkg` install `imgui` or any package in a system wide place like `dnf` does where `cmake` can find it?

Comment: Wouldn’t it be simpler to set `imgui_DIR`?

Answer (score 0):

I've decided to move the `vcpkg` directory into my project folder and to set `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` to the `vcpkg` directory. This way my project is self contained and I don't need to hard code the path to `vcpkg` to some location in my home directory.

I added this to my cmake:

```cmake
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux")
```

But I think the `vcpkg` `imgui` package is bugged because there are no `imgui_impl_*` files in the `imgui` installation of `vcpkg` so I've added `imgui` as a submodule instead.